# Orden de datos tabla SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

quisiera saber como puedo obtener un orden en especifico para un reporte, que el campo `Gravedad_Accidente`, se divida en "2, 3, 2" así sucesivamente. Este es la query:

```
select Fecha, Gravedad_Accidente
from (select convert(date, d.fecha_c) Fecha,
        cg.descripcion Gravedad_Accidente
        from dbtt d inner join ccgg cg on (d.gravedad_id = cg.codigo)
        where id in (select min(id)
                        from dbtt
                        where (fecha_c >= '2019-01-01')
                        group by s_id)
        and cg.codigo != 1) Tabla
group by Fecha, Gravedad_Accidente
```

El resultado es:

```
Fecha           Gravedad_Accidente
2019-01-02      2
2019-01-02      2
2019-01-02      3
```

Lo esperado es:

```
Fecha           Gravedad_Accidente
2019-01-02      2
2019-01-02      3
2019-01-08      2
2019-01-10      3
```

Comment: Tú pregunta es muy ambigua, si tu no sabes por cual columna se debe de ordernar menos la comunidad, aparte los resultados que presentas son pocos y no concuerdan los 3 registro de arriba con los 3 registro de abajo.

Comment: No entiendo tu orden, podrias poner un ejemplo mas amplio (y reducido, los otros campos no hacen al orden,o si?). Explica bien cual es la logica de ordenamiento. Como lo estas diciendo, no hay una logica. Uno y uno no es una logica para nada....

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que como puedo dar un orden a campo Gravedad_Accidente, de manera tal que quede "fatal, grave, fatal" y así, por algo puse, cual es el resultado que tengo y que es lo que espero.

Comment: En otras palabras solo te interesa ordenar por Gravedad_Accidente?

Comment: Lo usual sería crear una tabla paramétrica de GravedadAccidente, con el Tipo_Accdente como identificador, y una columna de "ponderación" o "peso" de importancia. Esa tabla la usarías en combinación con las restantes sólo a los efectos de ordenar como quieres.

Comment: Nose, si se entiende ahora

Comment: En efecto podrías realizar lo que indica @G'Kuan, aunque la tabla no es del todo necesaria ya que podrías realizar esto dentro de la misma consulta, por ejemplo con un CASE.

Comment: La fecha importa en el orden?

Comment: No, solamente ese campo

Answer (score 0):

puedes incluir en la subconsulta un campo orden el cual tome el valor dependiendo del id de gravedad accidente

ejemplo:

```
select Fecha, Gravedad_Accidente, count(*) as Cantidad_Accidente
from (select convert(date, d.fecha_c) Fecha,
        cg.descripcion Gravedad_Accidente,
        (CASE  
         WHEN cg.id=2 THEN 0 
         else 1  
        END ) as  orden
        from dbtt d inner join ccgg cg on (d.gravedad_id = cg.codigo)
        where id in (select min(id)
                        from dbtt
                        where (fecha_c >= '2019-01-01')
                        group by s_id)
        and cg.codigo != 1) Tabla
group by Fecha, orden
```

Comment: La idea está bien pero esto no haría que se ordenen intercalados, de igual manera se ordenarían todos los 1 primero y luego todos los 2 no?

Comment: claro, quedarían todos los 1 primeros y luego los 2, la idea es intercalado.

Answer (score 0):

Intentan utilizando un ***row_number*** con el argumento ***over***, con esto divides el conjunto de resultados generados en particiones, las cuales se les aplica una enumeración.

Por ejemplo:

```
select Fecha, Gravedad_Accidente
from (select convert(date, d.fecha_c) Fecha,
        cg.descripcion Gravedad_Accidente
        from dbtt d inner join ccgg cg on (d.gravedad_id = cg.codigo)
        where id in (select min(id)
                        from dbtt
                        where (fecha_c >= '2019-01-01')
                        group by s_id)
        and cg.codigo != 1) Tabla
group by Fecha, Gravedad_Accidente
order by row_number() over (partition by Gravedad_Accidente order by Gravedad_Accidente)
```

Te aconsejo que pruebes que tan rápido es la consulta. Por experiencia me ha tocado buscar soluciones distintas a un row_number ya que la consulta se vuelve un poco lenta.

> [row_number](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): Enumera los resultados de un conjunto de resultados.
>   Concretamente, devuelve el número secuencial de una fila dentro de una
>   partición de un conjunto de resultados, empezando por 1 para la
>   primera fila de cada partición.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a dar otra solucion, sin usar nada de partition (por los tiempos de ejecucion).

Simplemente hagamos una tabla con los datos uno abajo del otro y unamosla a otra tabla igual, y despues reordenemos por rownumber, que van a ser el mismo.

```
Select Fecha, gravedad_accidente, ROW_NUMBER() OVER [order by Fecha] as orden, 1 as orden2
from tabla
where Gravedad_Accidente = 2
union
Select Fecha, gravedad_accidente, ROW_NUMBER() OVER [order by Fecha] as orden, 2 as orden2
from tabla
where Gravedad_Accidente = 3
```

Esto deja una tabla con los 2 primero, los 3 segundo y un ROW_NUMBER(), y un orden2, que es nuestro invento para que siempre ordene los dos primeros.

Entonces hacemos

```
Select Fecha, gravedad_accidente
from
    (Select Fecha, gravedad_accidente, ROW_NUMBER() OVER [order by Fecha] as orden, 1 as 
    orden2
    from tabla
    where Gravedad_Accidente = 2
    union
    Select Fecha, gravedad_accidente, ROW_NUMBER() OVER [order by Fecha] as orden, 2 as orden2
    from tabla
    where Gravedad_Accidente = 3)
Order by orden, orden2;
```

Igual, para todas las soluciones que te dieron, hay que ver los explain plan para ver cual es mas rapida.